# jquery model form

Tags: jquery

```
function checkname(o) {
    var o = $('#log').val();                
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_name',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'username=' + o,
        success: function(o){
            if(o == 1) {
                 return o;
            }
            else {
                 o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
         updateTips( "not available" );
         return false; 
            }
        }
  });
}
```

this function related with form in model to check is available or no

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     height: 600,
     width: 550,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
    "save": function() {
        var bValid = true;
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

        bValid = bValid && checkname ( name, "name");


        if ( bValid ) {
                $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add_user',
            data: $('#myform :input').serialize(),

            success: function(i) {
                alert('sucess');
                            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},500)

            }
        });
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
   },
   close: function() {
     allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
   }
});
```

when i click save form wont save or wont close only in firebug return 1

i want if name available form save

Comment: can you please explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return something from the `checkname` function by returning it from the success callback, as the AJAX call is asynchronous.

Use a callback method to handle the result:

```
function checkname(o, whenValid) {
  var o = $('#log').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'check_name',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'username=' + o,
    success: function (o) {
      if (o == 1) {
        whenValid();
      } else {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips("not available");
      }
    }
  });
}

$("#dialog-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 550,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "save": function () {
      allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

      checkname(name, function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add_user',
                data: $('#myform :input').serialize(),

                success: function (i) {
                    alert('sucess');
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        location.reload()
                    }, 500)

                }
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");

      });


    },
    Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  },
  close: function () {
    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first ajax function, you are returning from within the scope of the success function, but the checkname function does not return anything. Even if it did, ajax is asynchronous, so returning the value of the returned data would not work.

You have to wait for the ajax calls to finish before you can start using the data, you'd do that by using the deferred return from the ajax function like so:

```
function checkname(name) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'check_name',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {username : name}
    });
}
```

And you'd use like:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        save: function () {
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
             //whatever "name" is ?
            checkname($('#log').val()).done(function(data) {
                if (data==1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'add_user',
                        data: $('#myform :input').serialize()
                    }).done(function(data2) {
                        //why use ajax only to reload the page ?
                        alert('sucess');
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }, 500);
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

Also, you seem to be using the same variables everywhere. The parameter for the checkname function is `o`, and inside the function you have a new variable called `o`, and then you use `o` in the ajax function, and you should try to be a little more inventive?